# Convert a string into a sequence of pairs of tuples

Tags: python, string, tuples

So I want to convert a string of data that I import (from a .txt file) into a new format.   I import a list from a text file - for example:

> 1231,123
>
> 2341,1210
>
> 342,12
>
> 5462,565

I use the following code

```
>>> fileHandle = open ( 'text.txt', 'r' )
>>> str1 = fileHandle.read()
>>> fileHandle.close()
>>> print str1
1231,123
2341,1210
342,12
5462,565

>>> list(str1)
['1', '2', '3', '1', ',', '1', '2', '3', '\n', '2', '3', '4', '1', ',', '1', '2', '1', '0', '\n', '3', '4', '2', ',', '1', '2', '\n', '5', '4', '6', '2', ',', '5', '6', '5', '\n']
```

But now I wish to convert it to the following tuple format:

```
((1231, 123), (2341, 1210), (342,12), (5462, 565))
```

I really need to find a way to convert this data to the format directly above.  I would greatly appreciate any help!

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as fp:
  data = tuple(ast.literal_eval(line) for line in fp)
```

Comment: Again, thank you.  Now, I might be a little greedy here.  I am creating this python code for a version of Abaqus (FEA software) that uses an old version of python (2.4), which does not recognize "with" statements nor "import ast" (nor ast.literal_eval()).   Is there any way to construct this same operation without those 2 items??
Thanks!

Comment: To replace `with`, just close the file manually after the fact. For the parsing, just split on the comma and shove the resultant elements through `int()`.